# VBA - Run Time Error 5 on adding ConditionalFormatting

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In my VBA application, i have used some conditional formating.When i changed the system decimal to Comma(,) instead of Dot(.). It starts giving me

> "Run Time Error 5 - Invalid Procedure Call or Argument"

at the line of add format condition

> `MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=formula_1`.

Code below..

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("financeSheet")        
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.UseSystemSeparators = True
       
        Dim MyRange As Range
        Set MyRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("financeSheet").Range(Target.Address)

        formula_1 = "=IF(OR($AV" & Target.Cells.row & "=""No"",AND($AV" & Target.Cells.row & "=""Yes"")),IF(Y" & Target.Cells.row & "=AJ" & Target.Cells.row & ",FALSE,TRUE),FALSE)"

        MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=formula_1
    End With
  End Sub
```

I worked fine while usual system setting as Dot(.). Please help to fix it

Comment: There is likely something wrong with your formula. I don't understand the logic of it, but the `OR`s and `AND`s seem strange. Write the exact formula you need into a cell, switch to the VBE and enter `? activecell.formula` into the immediate window. Then compare it to the content of `formula_1`

Comment: Forget my prev. comment. I was not aware about the fact that formulas in conditional formatting need to be in the current regional format.

Answer (score 0):

When you write a formula in a cell using VBA, you have the choice: You can use the property `formula` to write the formula language-independent - for Excel that means you write it in the US-English form, using comma as parameter separator and all English names for functions. This works no matter in with language and with regional settings your computer and Excel run.
If for any reason you want to write your formula using the current regional and language settings, you can use the property `FormulaLocal`.

Turns out when you write a formula into conditional formatting, you don't have the choice, you need to specify it with the local settings. In your case, you probably need to change the parameter separator from `","` to `";"`. Try

```
formula_1 = Replace(formula_1, ",", Application.International(xlListSeparator))
```

If, however, you want to be sure that your formulas will be crated correctly also on the computers of your colleagues or friends around the world, best bet is probably to write the (english) version of the formula into a cell somewhere on the sheet that is not visible and read the `formulaLocal`-property of that cell to get the translated formula.

Note that, as long as you use the correct listSeparator, Excel will accept the formula with english function names (or any names at all, you can type *Blablabla*), however, it will not fire when you are running in a different language.

If however, you create a sheet with correct conditional formatting formulas, save this workbook and open it with an Excel that runs in a different language, the formulas will be translated automatically and continue to work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case Error 5 happens in FormatConditions.Add method in the following context:

Cells.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
"=AND(A1>=$L1;A1<=$M1;$A1>"""")"

In sheet "X" above statement works properly. In sheet "Y" an event handler Worksheet_Activate calls RefreshTable method of a pivot table. Each time going back from sheet “Y” to “X” the FormatConditions.Add method fails. Replacing semicolons with commas back and forth in the Formula1 condition fixes the issue. (Note that my Excel (Mac coversion) accepts both colons and semicolons!) The following error handler in sheet “X” solves the issue:

On Error GoTo Alternative

```
Cells.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=AND(A1>=$L1;A1<=$M1;$A1>"""")"

GoTo Continue
```

Alternative:

```
Cells.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=AND(A1>=$L1,A1<=$M1,$A1>"""")"
```

Continue: