# Conditional formatting getting error in VBA

Tags: vba

I have a conditional formatting from VBA code for a column which applies when there is a change of value.

The column is actually a Price column, So when the price value is entered,based on some formulas i apply my condition. It is working when the decimal separator is "." (DOT) (For Example: 1.323)

**But when the decimal separator is "," in the system setting. I'm getting error when adding formula for conditional formatting** ..

**

- Code below..

**

```
   Dim MyRange As Range
    Set MyRange =Target.Address

    formula_1 = "=IF(OR($AV" & Target.Cells.row & "=""No"",AND($AV" & Target.Cells.row & "=""Yes"")),IF(Y" & Target.Cells.row & "=AJ" & Target.Cells.row & ",FALSE,TRUE),FALSE)"
    formula_2 = "=0"
    formula_3 = "=IF($N" & Target.Cells.row & "=""EUR"",TRUE,FALSE)"
    
    MyRange.Interior.Color = RGB(250, 191, 143)
    MyRange.FormatConditions.Delete
    MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=formula_1
    MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:=formula_2
    MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=formula_3
    
    MyRange.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)
    MyRange.FormatConditions(1).SetFirstPriority
    MyRange.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    
    MyRange.FormatConditions(2).StopIfTrue = True
    MyRange.FormatConditions(2).NumberFormat = "##0.00"

    MyRange.FormatConditions(3).StopIfTrue = True
    MyRange.FormatConditions(3).NumberFormat = "[$EUR] #,##0.0000"
```

[image]

Error triggered in line
`"MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=formula_1"` **Error code: 5**

Comment: Number with , comma was not recognised as value in excel, one simple solution is to add data validation to prevent ppl to add number with comma. If you can pulling data from other website, it will be better to pre-processing data before update your row value.

Comment: That is not true.. If you set the decimal seperator as "," in system setting itself. Excel is accepting.. (See the screenshot in question)... But for my code there seems to be some loop hole..

Comment: I see, too bad i never use such function, thanks for inform.

Comment: @KinSiang That depends on your machine language. There are several languages, which use `,` instead of `.` as the decimal separator.

Comment: @GK_ where exactly do you get your error? In VBA you would need to use the english formatting, even if your machine language is different. (e.g. when entering formuals through vba, you would need the english names)

Comment: On which line is the error raised and what error? `.NumberFormat = "[$EUR] #,##0.0000"` should behave correctly in both cases. Even for 12315487,23423. Of course, if you have "," as separator in this case. But if you have "." separator the pseudo number using comma separator is taken as string. Is the formula the problematic part? If yes, it is a matter of list separator, I think.

Comment: @GK_, ya i know about it, I work with a colleague from Spain, where they sysmbol is in comma, so they excel always got problem in calculation lol.

Comment: What kind of problem? It should be good to be a little more specific on this issue...

Comment: Error triggered in line "MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=formula_1" 
Error code: 5

Comment: So, it is obvious a matter of list separator. Which, probably, should be ";" in case of comma decimal separator and "," for dot separator. But read the answer posted by FunThomas and you will understand why and how it can be handled. Only for Conditional Formatted formulae.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA - Run Time Error 5 on adding ConditionalFormatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66346566/vba-run-time-error-5-on-adding-conditionalformatting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume it's not about the decimal separator but about the *list separator*. This separator is, among others, used as separator for function parameters.

Regular (cell-) formulas are always translated into the US versions. If you work on a system with list separator = ";" and enter a formula like `=OR(A1=1;B1=2)` in a cell, in VBA you will see `=OR(A1=1,B1=2)`. So far so good, all well known.

For some strange reasons, however, for formulas that are used in conditional formatting, the translation is not done, so you need to write the formula with the actual list separator character. You can get the current setting (it's not an Excel setting, it's a system setting) with `Application.International(xlListSeparator)`. However, once set, the formula will work when you open that workbook on a system with different settings (so some kind of translation happens).

If you want to be flexible, do something like this:

```
Const formula_1 = "=OR(A1=1<SEP>B1=2)"

Dim localFormula_1 As String
localFormula_1 = replace(formula_1, "<SEP>", Application.International(xlListSeparator))

MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=localFormula_1
```

Btw: You shouldn't have the decimal separator and the list separator set to the same character.

Comment: How do i change this part to comma.. MyRange.FormatConditions(3).NumberFormat = "[$EUR] #,##0.0000"

Comment: What kind of strange data do you have that you want to set the number format conditionally?

Comment: I want to add some prefix value for my price. in Number format.. It worked for DOT